# How do I check the visibillitiy of an element in a if-statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, visibility

im trying to check onCancelListener of my timerpicker-dialog the visibility of an radio-button (rdi_1), and want to setChecked(true) if visibility is VISIBLE.

```
timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

                            if (rdi_1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                rdi_1.setChecked(true); }
                            rdi_2.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }
```

Only rdi_2 gets unchecked

Comment: You’re closing your curly bracket after rdi_1.setChecked(true). Basically no matter what the if statement result is, you’ll set rdi_2 to unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check what do you get when you call `rdi_1.getVisibility()` first and see what kind of data you get back to make sure you're not comparing apples to oranges. You are setting the `rdi_2` to be unchecked regardless of your `if` statement.